# How can you constrain the intercept of a glmnet model to be positive?

Tags: regression, lasso, regularization, glmnet, elastic-net

If I use the `lower.limits = 0` argument, it doesn't apply to the intercept for some reason. I can't find any documentation as to why or how to do it. Any ideas? Below is a reproducible example. As you can see there's still negative intercepts.

```
# Load package
library(glmnet)

# Generate data
set.seed(12345)
n <- 1000
X <- cbind(1, runif(n, 0, 10), runif(n, 10, 20))
y <- -20 + X %*% c(2, 3, 4) + rnorm(n, 0, 1)
colnames(X) = c("intercept", "x1", "x2")

# Run lasso model
model <- glmnet(
    X,
    y,
    alpha = 0.5, # elastic net
    standardize = T,
    lambda = 10^seq(-10, 2, length = 10),
    lower.limits = 0
)

# Calculate lambda via BIC
beta <- as.matrix(model$beta)
beta["intercept", ] <- model$a0 # add intercept

# Show
beta

# Result
                s0       s1         s2         s3         s4         s5         s6         s7         s8         s9
intercept 57.93445 6.057752 -16.678764 -17.897615 -17.954596 -17.957241 -17.957364 -17.957370 -17.957370 -17.957370
x1         0.00000 1.929682   2.963308   3.018680   3.021269   3.021389   3.021395   3.021395   3.021395   3.021395
x2         0.00000 2.772042   3.923162   3.984883   3.987769   3.987903   3.987909   3.987909   3.987909   3.987909
```

Comment: Doesn't specifying `intercept=FALSE` do it?  You don't want to standardize because that will kill your constant column, so do the standardization yourself beforehand.

Comment: Thanks @whuber. However, `intercept = FALSE` doesn't solve it since it always sets the intercept to 0, regardless of the bounds. If I don't standardize (so if I set `standardize = FALSE`) same thing. I tried all four combinations of the `intercept` and `standardize` argument and I couldn't find one where the true intercept is negative and glmnet fits zero, or where the true intercept is positive and it fits positive. It's either zero or no bounds.

Comment: You have put your *own* intercept column into the model matrix: doesn't that do the trick?

Comment: It doesn't, my sim above already includes that in `cbind(1,...)`

Comment: Right.  So what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that I can't constrain the intercept. If I put it explicitly in the model via the `intercept = T` argument, it ignores the bound. If I exclude it via `intercept = F` and add it manually in the regressor matrix, it removes that column. Standardization doesn't help either. I think it has to do with the fact that `glmnet` calculates the intercept separately, since it has a special procedure to calculate it without bias.